# Program just works in one terminal

Tags: java, terminal

I'm executing this command in two different folders and in two different terminals:

```
for i in *_RG.bam; do k=`echo $i | sed  "s/.bam/_Reordered.bam/"` java -jar /home/Programas/picard-tools-1.107/ReorderSam.jar R=/local/Referencias/Homo_sapiens/UCSC/hg19/Sequence/Bowtie2Index/genome.fa  I= $i O= "$k" ; done
```

In one terminal it works ok, but on the other terminal the code is not working at all. It gives the next error.

```
Runtime.totalMemory()=1517289472
To get help, see http://picard.sourceforge.net/index.shtml#GettingHelp
Exception in thread "main" net.sf.samtools.util.RuntimeIOException: File not found: 
    at net.sf.samtools.util.BinaryCodec.<init>(BinaryCodec.java:102)
    at net.sf.samtools.util.BlockCompressedOutputStream.<init>(BlockCompressedOutputStream.java:127)
    at net.sf.samtools.BAMFileWriter.<init>(BAMFileWriter.java:50)
    at net.sf.samtools.SAMFileWriterFactory.makeBAMWriter(SAMFileWriterFactory.java:154)
    at net.sf.samtools.SAMFileWriterFactory.makeBAMWriter(SAMFileWriterFactory.java:136)
    at net.sf.samtools.SAMFileWriterFactory.makeSAMOrBAMWriter(SAMFileWriterFactory.java:246)
    at net.sf.picard.sam.ReorderSam.doWork(ReorderSam.java:118)
    at net.sf.picard.cmdline.CommandLineProgram.instanceMain(CommandLineProgram.java:179)
    at net.sf.picard.cmdline.CommandLineProgram.instanceMainWithExit(CommandLineProgram.java:120)
    at net.sf.picard.sam.ReorderSam.main(ReorderSam.java:77)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:  (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at net.sf.samtools.util.BinaryCodec.<init>(BinaryCodec.java:95)
    ... 9 more
```

When I call the program as `java -jar /home/ktroule/Programas/picard-tools-1.107/ReorderSam.jar -h` in a new terminal, it prints the help as I would expect.

After this I stopped using `ctrl+c` the terminal that was working properly and I exchanged the terminals to prove if the problem was related to the files or to the terminal. And the same happened, only one terminal worked (the same that was working previously).
I closed the terminal that wasn't working and opened a new one, but only on the original one the code works.

I have also compared on the terminal that works and the one that doesn't the output of printenv by usinf `diff` and both are the same excepet for the `WINDOWID` line.

Any guess on the problem?

I'm not closing the terminal that runs the code as I need it and I'm afraid of not being able to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that I can think that could cause a problem is that the command-line that you've quoted has a space after I= and O= before the corresponding filenames.

Is it possible that the command-lines that you're running are slightly different, and that this space is present in one but not the other?

Normally, the filename would be printed in the error log between "java.io.FileNotFoundException:" and "(No such file or directory)".

In your case, you've got two spaces, which implies that it's got an empty filename. This could well be caused by the space after I= and O=.

Comment: Now for some unknown reasons is working ok in a new terminal. Commands were always the same, as I was just copying and pasteing.